# In Rebol, what is the idiomatic way to read a text file line by line?

Tags: rebol

For the purpose of reading a text file line by line, without loading the entire file into memory, what is the common way to do this in Rebol?

I am doing the following, but I think (correct me if I'm wrong) that it loads the whole file into memory first:

```
foreach line read/lines %file.txt [ print line ]
```

Answer (score 5):

At least with Rebol2

```
read/lines/direct/part %file.txt 1
```

should come near to what you want

but if you want all lines one line after the other, it should be like

```
f: open/lines/direct %test.txt
while [l: copy/part f 1] [print l]
```

In theory you can supersede any function, even natives. I will try to give a new foreach

```
foreach_: :foreach
foreach:  func [
    "Evaluates a block for each value(s) in a series or a file for each line."
    'word [get-word! word! block!] {Word or block of words to set each time (will be local)}
    data [series! file! port!] "The series to traverse"
    body [block!] "Block to evaluate each time"
    /local port line
] [
    either any [port? data   file? data] [
        attempt [
            port: open/direct/lines data
            while [line:  copy/part port 1] [
                set :word line
                do :body 
                line
            ]
        ] 
        attempt [close port]
    ] [
        foreach_  :word :data :body
    ]
]
```

Probably the **set :word line** part and the attempt should be more elaborated in order to avoid name clashes and get meaningful errors.

Comment: But doesn't `open/lines/direct` load the whole file into memory? That's what I'm trying to avoid, as per my question.

Comment: No, 'open does just that - opens the file. Whereas 'read reads it. Well, maybe 'open bufferst at some modes, but there is also 'seek mode you could utilise - http://www.rebol.com/article/0199.html

Comment: From personal experience I can confirm, that open/lines/direct can use less memory than open/lines. But you will see the difference just, if you open bigger files. Probably there is a minimal internal buffer used, that will be always filled first.

Comment: I use open/direct/lines on some huge (bigger than memory) files and it just works as expected, doesn't load whole file into memory.

Comment: Like I said in my comment to draegtun: I was hoping to do something like the following in Ruby: `open('file.txt').each {|line| puts line}`. I guess one could write a variant of the `foreach` function in Rebol to do something similar that accepts a file or port. Can you change the behaviour of standard functions otherwise? (E.g. let `foreach` accept a `port!`) ?

Comment: In theory you can supersede any function even natives. I will try to give a new foreach.

Answer (score 2):

Yes [`open`](http://www.rebol.com/docs/words/wopen.html) is the way to go.   However like *sqlab* touches on the necessary `/lines` & `/direct` refinements are not present in Rebol 3 [`open`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/open.html) (yet).

The good news though is that you can still use [`open` to read in large files](http://www.rebol.net/wiki/Port_Examples#Large_File_Examples) in Rebol 3 without these refinements...

```
file: open %movie.mpg
while [not empty? data: read/part file 32000] [
    ;
    ; read in 32000 bytes from file at a time
    ; process data
]
close file
```

So you just need to wrap this up into a buffer and process a line at a time.

Here's a crude working example I've put together:

```
file: open/read %file.txt
eol: newline
buffer-size: 1000
buffer: ""
lines: []

while [
    ;; start buffering
    if empty? lines [
        ;; fill buffer until we have eol or EOF
        until [
            append buffer to-string data: read/part file buffer-size
            any [
                empty? data
                find buffer eol
            ]
        ]
        lines: split buffer eol
        buffer: take/last lines
    ]

    line: take lines
    not all [empty? data empty? buffer]
  ][
    ;; line processing goes here!
    print line
]

close file
```

Comment: That's quite a lot of code. I was hoping to do something like the following in Ruby: `open('file.txt').each {|line| puts line}`. I guess one could write a variant of the `foreach` function in Rebol to do something similar that accepts a file or port. Can you change the behaviour of standard functions otherwise? (E.g. let `foreach` accept a `port!` ?